# After upgrading to Angular universal Error retrieving icon google-colored

Tags: angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I recently upgraded by project from CLI to Universal.

I'm using `ngx-auth-firebaseui` in my project, After upgrading to universal i'm getting this below error

```
ERROR Error: Error retrieving icon :google-colored! 
    at SafeSubscriber._currentIconFetch._iconRegistry.getNamedSvgIcon.pipe.subscribe [as _error] ...
```

Please help to resolve this error.

Comment: I am having the same issue. by closing vs code and restarting the server but in my other project that solution did not work

Answer (score 0):

@MasterX. Did you copy the assets to angular.json? Step 7 of the Get Started Tutorial. https://ngx-auth-firebaseui.firebaseapp.com/getting-started. This solved for me the Problem.

In your `angular.json` under assets section add the following:

```
{
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "node_modules/ngx-auth-firebaseui/assets/",
    "output": "./assets/"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31450662)